# Wait for peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: with sync request

Tags: ios, bluetooth

What is best approach dealing with Core Bluetooth delegate with sync request?
By requirements I have to implement following method:

```
-(NSData *)dataWithRequest:(NSData *)request
            characteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {

    [_peripheralActive writeValue:request
                forCharacteristic:characteristic
                             type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
    // how to wait for response with _myData here?
    return _myData;
}
```

// CBPeripheralDelegate adopt

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
             error:(NSError *)error {
    // do staff
    _myData = characteristic.value;
}
```

Any waiting in same tread/queue will block delegate, waiting in another  tread/queue will return current _myData. Any help please.